# javascript replace closing table tag

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to add an `</div>` after my table closing tag.

```
 var addDiv = addStyleSpacingTable.replace(/</table>/g, `</table></div>`)
```

in the above the `/</table>/g`is the problem as it shows an parsing error, how do i get around this in js?

reaplcing the table was easy as it has no escape paramater:

eg:   var addDivTop = table1.replace(`/<table>/g`, `<div><table>`)

Comment: You need to escape `/` inside your regex. `/<\/table>/g`

Comment: thanks man yea almost its the ` \ ` i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a backslash `(\)`

```js
let addStyleSpacingTable="<table></table>"

var addDiv = addStyleSpacingTable.replace(/<\/table>/g, `</table></div>`)
console.log(addDiv)
```

Comment: The ` \ ` was what i was looking for man thanks, wil accept in 5min